# React-Native: Remove whitespace at top of screen on android

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to remove the whitespace at the top of the screen on iPhone and Android, as seen in the image below (iPhone left, Android right):

[image]

Rendered with the following code:

```js
return (
          <ScrollView style={{backgroundColor: colors.JBTan}}>
          </ScrollView>
      );
```

Adding the following code to my main index file (where AppRegistry is used), I am able to remove the whitespace, but only on iPhone:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './app/index';
import {SafeAreaView} from 'react-navigation'; //added this import

SafeAreaView.setStatusBarHeight(0); //added this line

AppRegistry.registerComponent('XXXXX', () => App);
```

This produces the following result (whitespace is gone on iPhone but not on Android):

[image]

How can I get the same result on Android?

Comment: Are you using React Native Navigation?

Comment: Yes, using 'react-navigation'.

Comment: Ok, React Native Navigation and React Navigation are two different projects. But I had the same problem with React Native Navigation and I had to set default settings to fix it. I found the solution here https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/blob/master/docs/docs/styling.md#enabling-persistent-styling-properties So I assume you might be missing a default config.

Comment: try <SafeAreaView foreIncets={{top: 'never'}}>

Answer (score 2):

You could try applying something like this in the styles.

```
{
position: 'absolute',
top: 0,
left: 0,
right: 0,
bottom: 0,
width: '100%',
height: '100%'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try in your navigation container:

```
<Provider>
 <RootStack.Navigator>
  <RootStack.Screen
    options={{ headerShown: false}}>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting a extra space in top of your screen , You have to add only this `<StatusBar translucent={true}></StatusBar>` line in your return method inside main view. after adding this , extra space has been removed.[with extra space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56MPF.png).      [without extra space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lku2h.png)